# How to modify a getter and setter, to handle a null reference exception

Tags: c#, reference, null, setter, getter

I am parsing a JSON String, and deserialize it. Works fine now, but I have a problem handling a value, which is an empty string or null.

This properties have 2 values (for example link and value). Normally. But it can happen that the property I read, has null (so no link and no value).

I wrote the getter and setter like this.

```
private ResolvedBy myVar1;
public ResolvedBy resolved_by
{
 get
 {
  if (myVar1 == null)
  {
  myVar1 = new ResolvedBy();
  return myVar1;
  }
  // if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myVar1.link) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myVar1.value))
  if (myVar1.ToString() == String.Empty)
  {
  myVar1 = new ResolvedBy();
  return myVar1;
 }
 return myVar1;
}
set { myVar1 = value; }
```

}

and the class has following code

```
public class ResolvedBy //
{
public string link { get; set; }
public string value { get; set; }
}
```

If I now re-instantiate the object using the new modifier, the link and value are also null. Is there a way to fill link and value with an empty string in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `link` and `value` a default value:

```
public class ResolvedBy
{
    public string link { get; set; } = "";
    public string value { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thats helps a lot !

Comment: @Glowhollow: maybe, but not really what you have asked for(_"in this particular case"_). It will always assign `String.Empty` not only here.

Comment: I do agree with @TimSchmelter

Comment: Okay, I've tried that now. The problem that has now occurred is that the deserialization, whose values are no longer written to the properties, should only be in the case where the property itself has a null value or an empty string.

Unfortunately no solution in sight yet.

Answer (score 1):

> If I now re-instantiate the object using the new modifier, the link
>   and value are also null. Is there a way to fill link and value with an
>   empty string in this particular case ?

Sure

```
return new ResolvedBy { link = "", value = "" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this now, I have updated it to return an "" if the property is null

```
class ResolvedBy
{
    string link;
string value;
    public string Link
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.link == null ? "" :this.link 
        }
        set
        {
            this.link= (value ==null ? "" : value);
        }
    }
 public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.value == null ? "" : this.value); 
        }
        set
        {

this.value =( value == null ? "" : value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry, to say that, got also the "The object reference was not defined for an object instance." error still....

Comment: This is unnecessary complicated, e.g. `get { return this.link == null ? "" : this.link }` can be shortened to `get => link ?? "";`. The same for the setters.